# Controlling number of http request coming to system - Backpressure

Tags: rest

We had a use case where our client by mistake sends 10000 request, for each request we had to immediately send a ID and then enrich the data with multiple DB calls/rest call and finally response back to Kafka topic. Due to this much processing the whole system went down including the underlined system as along with Kakfa we also publish to MQ which again goes for further processing.

Ask is to control the number of requests client can send, we though of controlling it to store the threshold in DB based on per day or per hours and start rejecting once they reach the threshold but this requires computation and DB hits.

Is there any tool or out of box solution with minimum effort and without adding performance load to system? We are looking for some kind of Back pressure technique like in Spring webflux etc.

It is spring boot application on Java 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backpressure works the other way around, when you are consuming a client that is emitting more than you can process. What you are looking for is **Rate Limiter**.

You can take a look at the [Resilience4J Rate Limiter](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/ratelimiter)

Comment: Thanks.. I had figured out myself.. using spring API gateway for same..